# How to filter dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the following data:

```
List(Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187513, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc), 
     Map(event_id -> DEF, event_name -> added, timestamp -> 1478187520, member_id -> 111),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187522, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187618, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc))
List(Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187618, member_id -> 222, category -> web, field1 -> def))
List(Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187513, member_id -> 333, category -> web, field1 -> abc), 
     Map(event_id -> DEF, event_name -> added, timestamp -> 1478187520, member_id -> 333),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187522, member_id -> 333, category -> web, field1 -> def),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187618, member_id -> 333, category -> web, field1 -> abc))
```

How can I delete all `List[Map[..]]` elements that have `field1` equal to `def` for at least one entry inside `Map`?

The result should be this one:

```
List(Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187513, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc), 
     Map(event_id -> DEF, event_name -> added, timestamp -> 1478187520, member_id -> 111),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187522, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187618, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc))
```

This is my draft code, but I cannot compile it:

```
            val result = dataset.filter({
              list => !list.exists(t => t.getOrElse("field1","").equals("def"))
            })
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Please post.

Comment: @Sami: It says that `t.getOrElse("field1","")` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val data = List(List(Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187513", "member_id" -> "111", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "abc"),
     |       Map("event_id" -> "DEF", "event_name" -> "added", "timestamp" -> "1478187520", "member_id" -> "111"),
     |       Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187522", "member_id" -> "111", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "abc"),
     |       Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187618", "member_id" -> "111", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "abc")),
     |       List(Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187618", "member_id" -> "222", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "def")),
     |       List(Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187513", "member_id" -> "333", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "abc"),
     |         Map("event_id" -> "DEF", "event_name" -> "added", "timestamp" -> "1478187520", "member_id" -> "333"),
     |         Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187522", "member_id" -> "333", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "def"),
     |         Map("event_id" -> "ABC", "event_name" -> "visited", "timestamp" -> "1478187618", "member_id" -> "333", "category" -> "web", "field1" -> "abc")))


scala> def filterData(xs: List[List[Map[String, String]]]): List[List[Map[String, String]]] = {
     | xs.filter(sumList => !sumList.exists(x => x.getOrElse("field1", "").equals("def")))
     | }
filterData: (xs: List[List[Map[String,String]]])List[List[Map[String,String]]]


scala> val output = filterData(data)
output: List[List[Map[String,String]]] = List(List(Map(timestamp -> 1478187513, field1 -> abc, event_name -> visited, category -> web, member_id -> 111, event_id -> ABC), Map(event_id -> DEF, event_name -> added, timestamp -> 1478187520, member_id -> 111), Map(timestamp -> 1478187522, field1 -> abc, event_name -> visited, category -> web, member_id -> 111, event_id -> ABC), Map(timestamp -> 1478187618, field1 -> abc, event_name -> visited, category -> web, member_id -> 111, event_id -> ABC)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your keys are `String`s and you concatenate those `List`s into a big `List`--i.e. a `List[List[Map[String, Any]]]` called `data`, then you can do this:

`data.filterNot(_.exists(_.get("field1").contains("def")))`

Incidentally, that data structure is pretty complex, which makes it harder to reason about and therefore harder to see how to process it. Its complexity also would make a partition strategy tougher, which could lead to poor performance. I suggest you consider ways to simplify your data model.